# Set audio sample bit depth in Java

Tags: java, javasound

Here is my code. I am using javax.sound.sampled.* for the audio classes.

```
byte[] myAudioByteArray = new byte[]{0, 127,    127, 127, -127, 127};

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(myAudioByteArray);

AudioInputStream stream = new AudioInputStream(bais, new AudioFormat(SampleRate.R_44100, 24, 1, true, false), myAudioByteArray.length)
```

The amplitude is bitdepth, so how does java allow you to set the bitdepth of a each sample?
I have set the bit depth of the resulting file to be 24 bit depth, so in theory I should be able to set the samples at the specific depth range (16,777,216).
The problem is I don't know how you do this with the bytes you feed into the ByteArrayInputStream object that then goes into the AudioInputStream object because they are signed.
I thought maybe you could convert the bytes to their binary representation and then combine 3 of them to get 3 bytes for the 16,777,216 range, but that theory is incorrect from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought maybe you could convert the bytes to their binary representation and then combine 3 of them to get 3 bytes for the 16,777,216 range, but that theory is incorrect from what I can tell.

Not sure, why this didn't work for you.

Each sample has to be encoded, either [big endian or little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Here are some methods from the audio processing library [jipes](https://github.com/hendriks73/jipes/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tagtraum/jipes/audio/AudioSignalSource.java#L238) that show how you can decode bytes to samples from either little or big endian to `int`:

```
private static int byteToIntLittleEndian(final byte[] buf, final int offset, final int bytesPerSample) {
    int sample = 0;
    for (int byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < bytesPerSample; byteIndex++) {
        final int aByte = buf[offset + byteIndex] & 0xff;
        sample += aByte << 8 * (byteIndex);
    }
    return sample;
}

private static int byteToIntBigEndian(final byte[] buf, final int offset, final int bytesPerSample) {
    int sample = 0;
    for (int byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < bytesPerSample; byteIndex++) {
        final int aByte = buf[offset + byteIndex] & 0xff;
        sample += aByte << (8 * (bytesPerSample - byteIndex - 1));
    }
    return sample;
}
```

Once the value is decoded you still have to cast to your target interval. If you were interested in a 2 bytes format, i.e. bit depth of 16, you'd simply do this:

```
final int sample = byteToIntLittleEndian(buf, sampleOffset, bytesPerChannel);
final short shortSample = (short)sample;
```

The cast takes care of the overflow.

With 3 bytes it's a little more complicated. You need to know the value range first. Note that because you are interested in signed values, it's not `[0,2^24]`, but:

```
/**
 * A constant holding the minimum value a <code>signed24bit</code> can
 * have, -2<sup>22</sup>.
 */
private static final int MIN_VALUE_24BIT = -2 << 22;

/**
 * A constant holding the maximum value a <code>signed24bit</code> can
 * have, 2<sup>22</sup>-1.
 */
private static final int MAX_VALUE_24BIT = -MIN_VALUE_24BIT-1;
```

Then you use that to convert to a signed sample value like this:

```
final int sample = byteToIntLittleEndian(bud, sampleOffset, bytesPerChannel);
final int threeByteSample = sample > MAX_VALUE_24BIT ? sample + MIN_VALUE_24BIT + MIN_VALUE_24BIT : sample;
```

Comment: All of that makes sense and works except for the last part, how do I out the binary number into a byte? Bytes are signed and I don't know how to stick it in one because I am putting the bytes into a ByteArrayInputStream.

Comment: Frankly, I don't exactly understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to manually create a byte buffer that contains 24 bit sound? Perhaps you want to elaborate in an edit to your original question.